# Angular 'app-***' is not a known element - Lazy loading modules

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem that i can't understand.

Basically, i have the app module (app.module.ts) with a async route (app-routing.module.ts) to other module (design-system.module.ts). A component (design-system.component.ts) of this async module calls a component of a third module (ButtonModule). The component of main module gives no problem (AppComponent) when calling the third module, but the async module gives an error (DesignSystemModule).

**Files**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'design-system',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./design-system/design-system-routing.module').then(
        (m) => m.DesignSystemRoutingModule
      ),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**design-system.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonModule } from '../components/button/button.module';
import { DesignSystemRoutingModule } from './design-system-routing.module';
import { DesignSystemComponent } from './design-system.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DesignSystemComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, DesignSystemRoutingModule, ButtonModule],
})
export class DesignSystemModule {}
```

**design-system-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DesignSystemComponent } from './design-system.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: DesignSystemComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DesignSystemRoutingModule {}
```

**design-system.component.html**

```
<app-button></app-button>
<p style="color: white;">design-system works!</p>
```

**button.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [ButtonComponent],
})
export class ButtonModule {}
```

**The error**

```
error NG8001: 'app-button' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Angular CLI: 12.2.1
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.1
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.1
@schematics/angular             12.2.1
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Comment: Sorry guy, but have you tried to restart your server, sometimes, the angular don't update somethings :/

Comment: You need to put the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: @Hoch yes. i did it already.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i'll update this question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loadChildren should load "design-system.module.ts" **not** the "design-system-routing.module", is the design-system.module who import "the design-system-routing.module"

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'design-system',
    loadChildren: () =>      //import the design-system.module
      import('./design-system/design-system.module').then(
        (m) => m.DesignSystemModule
      ),
  },
];
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Sorry for that! I was totally blind.

Comment: It's more common that you think :)

Comment: Any chance you can provide feedback on the issue with Angular 14? I have the exact same setup, and due to the newest version of Angular, it doesn't allow you to import this way anymore. It wants the setup to be 
loadChildren: async () => (await import('./login/login.module')).LoginModule
However, this fails with the same issue. The Component that I declare in my LoginModule doesn't get loaded. When the LoginModule's router navigates to the component indicated by the route, and then calls the other component (declared in LoginModule) in the html it fails to find the component.